parachain full node stops sync with parachain. finalized stays at zero
We're running a full node for a parachain based on PSDK-1.13. At startup, both relay and para are catching up nicely and at some point are in sync.
Then, the relay keeps syncing, but the para block import stalls. Stalling means we see this forever
[Parachain] ⚙️  Preparing  0.0 bps, target=#6221653 (10 peers), best: #6221647 (0x7563…1851), finalized #0 (0xcded…58da), ⬇ 58 B/s ⬆ 0.3kiB/s    

noteworthy:

finalized: 0 (but the para actually finalizes fine and continues producing blocks)
reproducible: restarting will again catch up and then stall

Logs with -lsync=trace,network=debug
https://gist.github.com/brenzi/11cd698c465ad56c63ba779cd6089ce0

This is related to https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/issues/4903, which basically means you can't sync a reasonably sized para from scratch as resolving forks in the fork tree becomes way too expensive.
It has been resolved by https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/pull/4922, which means that upgrading the collator binary to >= polkadot-v1.14.1 will resolve the issue.
A short term remedy would be to copy a synced para db to the collator you are trying to sync.
